# Using 'stub' correctly

Tags: junit, easymock, powermock

I'm trying to test a method which calls a couple of other methods in the class. I'd like the other methods to be stubbed out so they don't get executed. I had thought it was a simple matter of using 'stub'. For example:

```
class Fubar {  
void fu() {  
    // . . .  
    bar();  
}  

void bar() {  
    // . . .  
}  

void testFu() {  
    Fubar fubar = new Fubar();  
    stub (method (Fubar.class, "bar"));  

    replay();  

    fubar.fu();  

    verifyAll();  
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. It is terminating inside the 'bar' method when I had expected it to be basically a no-op. Am I using it incorrectly?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you remove the replay method?

Comment: I really can't do that. There's a lot more mock stuff happening than what I've shown here and if I take that out then I'll get actual execution of a bunch of objects that I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal problem of your approach is your `fubar` instance, which is under test, has nothing related to your stub.

I suggest you to [use `createPartialMock()`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.9/apidocs/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html#createNicePartialMock%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) which allows you to create new instance of `Fubar` and mock only `bar()` method there. So this way you can test your `fubar` instance (produced by `createPartialMock()`) and record behavior of `bar()`.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a shot. Thanks.